# Laravel - search by title?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How to search by `title` in the `ServiceType` only? There is also a title field in the `Package` which should be avoided

For example, in the Model:

```
class Package extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'package';

    function serviceType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ServiceType');
    }

    public static function getPackagesByServiceType($service)
    {
        return Package::with('serviceType')->where('title', '=', $service);
    }
}
```

Note:

There is a service_type_id field in the `Package` and `id`, `title` fields in the `serviceType`

in the controller:

```
$packages = Package::getPackagesByServiceType('something')->get();
```

No result appeared for some reason? It should search for `something` in the `serviceType`

It seem it wouldn't work to combine `with()` and `where()`. When I remove the `where()` and it work.

Comment: did you try logging the actual query that is being executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `where()` like that to filter by a related model. You should use `whereHas()` instead:

```
public static function getPackagesByServiceType($service)
{
    return Package::with('serviceType')->whereHas('serviceType', function($q) use ($service){
        $q->where('title', '=', $service);
    });
}
```

Note if you don't need `serviceType` in the packages afterwards you don't have to eager load it, ergo you can remove the `with('serviceType')`

---

Also if you call `get()` in the controller you should use a [query scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#query-scopes). It offers the same functionality but it's not a static function and it's the *Laravel way*

```
public function scopeByServiceType($query, $service){
    return $query->with('serviceType')->whereHas('serviceType', function($q) use ($service){
        $q->where('title', '=', $service);
    });
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
$packages = Package::byServiceType('something')->get();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class Package extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'package';

    function serviceType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ServiceType');
    }

    public static function getPackagesByServiceType($service)
    {
        return Package::with('serviceType')->where('title', '=', $service)->get();
    }
}
```

You forgot the ->get();

Comment: I didnt forget `->get();` I used `->get();` in the controller.

Answer (score -3):

The `->get()` should be in the Model

```
public static function getPackagesByServiceType($service)
{
    return Package::with('serviceType')->where('title', '=', $service)->get(); // here
}
```

and in the controller it should be like this:

```
$packages = Package::getPackagesByServiceType('something');
```

Hope that helps... I had similar issues in my Model - Controller structure....

Comment: And you don't need the "=" in your where clause: `->where('title', $service)` is sufficient.

Comment: I have tried that and it didn't work. Problem it has not joined the tables when I include `where()'

Comment: and one more thing... if you have a title column in both tables use either:
`->where('serviceTypes.title', $service)`you need to use the name of the table here, not the name of the Model, so assuming the tablename is `serviceTypes`.

Comment: `return $this->belongsTo('ServiceType');` should be 
`return $this->belongsTo('ServiceType', 'service_type_id');`
The name of the column is not conform with the namng conventions and therefore needs to be specified here...

Comment: Yep I know but it doesn't work. It seem it can't use `where()` when using `with()`. It would not work.